# indexed image in python3 pillow

Tags: image, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create an uin8 image with a colormap using pillow. I did the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im = np.hstack(    (np.ones((200,100))*255, np.zeros((200,100)) )).astype(np.uint8)
pim = Image.new("L", im.shape, 0)
print(im.min(), im.max())
pim.putdata(im)
pim.save("out.gif")
```

This should create a black and white image, but for some reason its just pitch black. What am i doing wrong here?
I am using: Pillow 4.2.1 (python 3.6)